# Euclidian embedding of lines

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm looking for a way to convert a set of lines in R^3 into points in R^n so that distance between any pair of points points is a good approximation of the distance between corresponding pair of lines. Can anyone see a practical way of doing this?

Comment: This won't be easy, since it is possible for line A to be close to both lines B and C, while lines B and C are far from each other --- that can't happen with points.

Comment: Maybe you could try transform this set in a manifold. For example, the set of all lines in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a mobius band.